# Why can a function returning Variant be called with additional parameters?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, compiler-errors

This yields a compile-time error (wrong number of arguments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Call returnsBoolean(1)
End Sub

Function returnsBoolean() As Boolean
End Function
```

This, however, compiles fine (and throws a run-time error *after* returning from `returnsVariant`):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Call returnsVariant(1)
End Sub

Function returnsVariant() As Variant
End Function
```

Why?

Comment: So interesting. I just tested it. I will have a dig around, see if I can find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hopefully make it clear:

**First example**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
  Dim b as Boolean  
  b = returnsBoolean
  Debug.Print b(1) ' error, because b is not an array
End Sub

Function returnsBoolean() As Boolean
End Function
```

**Second example**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
  Dim V as Variant
  V = returnsBoolean
  Debug.Print V(1) ' OK, because Variants can contain arrays
End Sub

Function returnsBoolean() As Variant
End Function
```

It's because the (1) is being interpreted as an array index and not the arguments to the function. Another way of thinking of it is that your code is being interpreted as

```
(returnsBoolean())(1)
```

**EDIT**

In response to the comment below, the following gives a subscript error:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    returnsVariant 1, 2, 5
End Sub

Function returnsVariant() As Variant
 Dim x(1 To 1, 2 To 2, 3 To 3) As Long
 x(1, 2, 3) = 10
 Dim V As Variant
 V = x
 returnsVariant = V
End Function
```

so `returnsVariant 1,2,5` is being interpreted as `(returnsVariant())(1,2,5)`. In my version of Excel, putting `1,2,3` causes VBA to crash and burn

Comment: I thought about the Array option as well, but if that is the case, why does `returnsVariant 1, 2` compile? (No `Call`, and arrays cannot be accessed without parenthesis.)